# Finding Signed Angle Between Three Points

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, angle

I have seen explanations of how to find the angle defined by three points, A, B and C.  However, all the examples I have seen yield absolute angular values.  That is to say, the angle value for A->B->C is the same positive value as the value for C->B->A.  I am trying to calculate positive or negative angular values, using the right hand rule to determine sign.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The angle will be positive, that is, the ray $\overrightarrow{{\bf B}{\bf C}}$ will be anticlockwise from the ray $\overrightarrow{{\bf B}{\bf A}}$ (by an angle less than $\pi$) iff the determinant of the matrix $$\pmatrix{{\bf A} - {\bf B} & {\bf C} - {\bf B}}$$ is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your solution must be positive because they are all part of a triangle with vertices ABC.  If the angles could be negative, then the angles wouldn't add up to $180^o$.  Or you would have to have an angle be larger than $180^o$ to make up for the other angles.  We can have other angles be negative because they are relative to a ray, usually the x-axis.  One direction from this ray is positive, the other is negative.  What you are mentioning is a ray, but it changes for your two examples.  For $A\to B\to C$, the ray that the angle is relative to is ray $A\to B$, making the angle indeed positive.  Working it from the other direction changes the ray and the way you have to view the angle.  Hope I answered correctly and fulfillingly and do mind my using of the work ray at the end.